# Spring Cloud config server fails to start

Tags: java, spring, git, spring-boot

I am following entries in the application.properties

```
spring.application.name=spring-cloud-config-server
server.port=8888
#spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri:file:///C:/software/codebase/microservices/git-localconfig-repo
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri:https://github.com/XYZ/limits-service
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri.username=test
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri.password=test
```

I have the following code for spring cloud server application.

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer;

    @EnableConfigServer
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    public class SpringConfigServerApplication {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(SpringConfigServerApplication.class, args);
        }
    
    }
```

I am getting the following error

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-02-24 01:39:52.356 ERROR 20804 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Invalid config server configuration.

Action:

If you are using the git profile, you need to set a Git URI in your configuration.  If you are using a native profile and have spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true, you need to use a composite configuration.

Comment: None of the previously asked question has solved my solution. With active profile as native, that sources the application.properties itself. I need the git profile only, not the native one.

Answer (score 0):

In this line should be an equals:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/XYZ/limits-service
```

instead of

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri:https://github.com/XYZ/limits-service
```

Comment: I have already tried with equals also, but no luck

Comment: Try add this configuration: `spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=main` it indicates the branch that should be used.